# Add default content to backend users in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

My web service holds files, which users can manipulate and then view. 
I create new users automatically with an email address.

The difficulty I'm facing, is how can I set some default content to every user? I can't just link to the same files, because the user has the ability to manipulate those files, and so all the other user's files will be changed as well.

my model:

```
class Contentfile(models.Model):
    content = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(upload_to='uploads/', content_types=['video/mp4', 'application/pdf', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'],max_upload_size=104857600,blank=True, null=True, help_text='Upload a file to add it to the content the app displayes')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    file_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Contentfiles')
    orderValue = models.IntegerField("presentation order")
```

Comment: Can your users manipulate the actual files, or only their `Contentfile` metadata?

Comment: Im using s3 to store the files. when a user "deletes" or "edits" the file, it is in fact the actual file.

Comment: I would add a `Contentfile.is_template` boolean field, set to `True` for the default content, and then create a full copy of the actual file and clear the `is_template` flag _on the first manipulation attempt_, but your question is really too broad for Stack Overflow. Take a look at [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write).

Comment: Interesting read, I think what I will do is cancel the option to edit the file and leave only the option to delete. than have my post delete signal listener, that is currently in charge of deleting the file from the s3 server, only do it if the is_template is false.